# Adding hard drive failed

Tags: hard-drive, mythbuntu, mythtv

I was using Von Welch's [instructions](http://v2kblog.blogspot.com/2007/05/adding-second-hard-drive.html) to install a 500 GB Seagate drive to write the recordings to.

Everything seemed to be going okay until `mkfs /dev/sdb1` then we get an error message:

```
mkfs.ext2: inode_size (128) * inodes_count (0) too big for a
filesystem with 0 blocks, specify a higher inode_ratio (-i)
or lower inode count (-N)
```

My son is trying to help me but this is beyond him. Our knowledge of UNIX/Linux is very limited. At work the support people just sent me a line by line cook book.

The computer is a Gateway MDP e4000 with Mythbuntu installed on a PATA drive and we are adding a SATA drive for the second drive. The BIOS sees the drive.

I would appreciate any help you can give us.

Answer (score 1):

yeah your getting that error because your formatting an extended partition, and you need a primary partition with SATA. If you were setting up an IDE slave device this would work, but you need a partition table with SATA. Extended partitions don't work that way.
So, if you want to start over this should work out, its not too complicated but you definitely want to be sure which drive is which.

I'm guessing you just need one data partition on the spinner, and use the solid for the boot device, so run fdisk -l and be darn sure you know exactly which drive your going to format.

I am doing this procedure as I write this so I do not miss something, a mistake can, or rather will most likely ruin your system.

Run

```
fdisk -l
```

chose the drive your going to use. In my case I have a couple other drives, so I'm

using Sdc. I think your best to drop into root instead of just sudo, so run

```
sudo -s
```

Now your as root

Next we need to create a partition, so the new drive has a table so the system can

find it.

```
root@xxx #fdisk /dev/sdx
```

where x is your drive letter

This will pull up a GUI

fist we need to create a new partition:

```
Command (m for help): n
```

e   extended

p   primary partition (1-4)

We want a primary, so we use 'p'

```
p
```

This is the only partition on a clean disk

```
Partition number (1-4): 1
```

I just use the defaults for the start and end sector

Then write the new table and exit with the following

```
Command (m for help): w`
```

NOTE once in fdisk, if you realize you are in the wrong drive, or make a mistake just

enter 'q' which quits without writing any of the instructions you have chose. Until

you run 'w' nothing changes.

Now you need to format it as a ext.4

```
root@xxx# mkfs.ext4 -L disk2 /dev/sdx1
```

*Any errors try unmounting the drive with umount*

Now the partition is ready we need to make a place to put it, and add an entry to the

file that lists the drives when the system boots.

exit out of root

```
exit

sudo blkid
```

> dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="some hash" >TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="string -01"
>
> /dev/sda5: UUID="some string like above" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="string - 02"
>
> /dev/sda6: LABEL="root" UUID="string" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="string"
>
> /dev/sdc1: LABEL="storage" UUID="0BED64E911A2FAD2" TYPE="ext4" >PARTUUID="c07Aab2a-01"

We find the drive and partition just wrote, and copy the UUID='string value' and TYPE='ext4', so above example sdc1 is our second hard drive. Copy'UUID="0BED64E911A2FAD2" TYPE="ext4""' Get rid of the quotes

name it something that makes sense in your world`

```
sudo mkdir /data0
```

Use whatever editor you know how to use, if that means none:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

use the down arrow key, to scroll to the bottom, and by a new last entry by pasting your clipboard contents. Now use the back arrow, till the cursor is just right of the TYPE= and backspace to erase 'TYPE=', next use the left arrow key to get a couple spaces right from the end of the UUID string. Add the (whatever you named it from mkdir). There should be comments which explain the proper formatting fstab uses, and a few entries, if not you better check that you spelled /etc/fstab correctly. Anyway it should look like this

> UUID=some string /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
>
> /swapfile                              none    swap   sw         0       0
>
> UID=0BED64E911A2FAD2 /data0       ext4        defaults      0       2

then press

```
ctrl + o
```

when asked are you sure, type "y" then press return twice, and then exit with

```
ctrl + x
```

Finally finish with

```
sudo mount -a
```

Now your drive will show up. When you reboot it will automatically mount on boot.

You do not want to use this to mount removable drives, only use fixed hardware, and
only use this method for SATA. 
Sorry about my grammar, I barely speak English and hope this can be understood. I also need to be clear this is only for adding a second drive to be used as storage, if you are trying to replace a failed boot drive in which case your probably in read only state there is separate procedure which is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Disk Utility or Gparted to format the hard drive as ext4.  If that fails, delete the partitions and the partition tables on the hard drive and start from scratch with Gparted.

After that, all you have to do is put an entry in /etc/fstab so that the drive automounts at boot.

It seems that you've made things way more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting that your disk is physically broken but you should definitely confirm that it isn't. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sdb
```

This will show you a table with a header (ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME FLAG, etc.). Find a line with Reallocated_Sector_Ct and make sure that the number under the column RAW_VALUE is 0. If it isn't, that means that the drive is failing and it's time to replace it.

Then create a single partition (if that's what you want) using fdisk, cfdisk and then create the filesystem on it:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L 500GB /dev/sdb1
```